# Button on the phone does not respond

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[_imgviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(recordButtonTouchDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[_imgviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(recordButtonTouchUpOutside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[_imgviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(recordButtonTouchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_imgviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(recordDragOutside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
[_imgviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(recordDragInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[self addSubview:_imgviewBtn];


- (void)recordButtonTouchDown {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(recordButtonTouchDown)]) {
        [self.delegate recordButtonTouchDown];
    }
}

- (void)recordButtonTouchUpInside {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(recordButtonTouchUpInside)]) {
        [self.delegate recordButtonTouchUpInside];
    }
}

- (void)recordButtonTouchUpOutside {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(recordButtonTouchUpOutside)]) {
        [self.delegate recordButtonTouchUpOutside];
    }
}

- (void)recordDragOutside {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(recordDragOutside)]) {
        [self.delegate recordDragOutside];
    }
}

- (void)recordDragInside {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(recordDragInside)]) {
        [self.delegate recordDragInside];
    }
}
```

If I click `UIControlEventTouchDown`, When leave , `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` No response. if `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` leave, Same non response `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`, Simulator is no problem running on the phone there is a problem, iOS10.1, Xcode8.1;

please help me...

Comment: Can you please check IBOutlet for _imgviewBtn? Also make sure userInteraction is enabled.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled is YES, I create my own demo, which is responsive,

But I can't do it in my project, and create a new class test in my project,

Also not

Comment: Not clear what you asked for. Edit the lines below your code and ask specific question and please be clear.

Comment: I would like to send a voice, when the finger when the lift to send, lift up on the slide, cancel the send, and now is not responding to lift the method

Answer (score 0):

If this was code written inside a custom button class, then when you initiate a class object (actual button), make sure to set the following property like so:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

please set UIImageview property as UserInteraction enable = true

imgYouimage.userInteractionEnable =  True;

It will work.